# Spring Boot - Mybatis - PostgreSQL function doesn't persist data in insert

Tags: function, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am calling a function using spring mybatis implementation and I can see that the data I try to insert is not being persisted in DB, the execution finishs withour problems, but when I go to DB and try to find the inserted data, it never appears.

Observations:
1. I can get data from the select method.
2. I tried to put a SQL inside insert tag and it works fine.

```
<select id="getListEntity" resultMap="entidadListaMap">
    select * from pkg_cl_ses.sps_get_entity_list()
</select>

<insert id="insertEntity"  parameterType="com.mb.dr.model.Entity">
    select pkg_cl_ses.spi_entity(#{field1}, #{field2})
</insert>
```

Hope you can kindly help me to deal with this problem and to solve it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds as if you are missing a `commit` somewhere

Comment: You could set AUTOCOMMIT on

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. The problem was that I executed that code under a JUnit test so I was not able to persist data.
It works fine just running my application.